# "BarLegend" Ticks inteference

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, contour

I have a ContourPlot in mathematica which has a legend BarLegend as shown below. I have three problems with the "Tick numbers":

(1) they are interfering each other (or are too close):

probable solutions:

a. select specific numbers to show in legend bar, for example, {-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1}.

b. show the tick labels vertically in order to prevent them from interference.

c. increase the length of legend bar.

(2) I want to change tick numbers font to "Times"

(3) I defined the minimum maximum of BarLegend (-1,1) but the minimum maximum themselves are not included. (I want to have them in legend bar)

[image]

The code is plotting the distribution function f1 as a function of x and y:

```
    f[e_, p_, v_] = 1000/(Sqrt[10 Pi]) e (e^2 - p^2) (1/v)^5 Exp[-5/2 (3 e^2 + p^2)/v^2];
plot = Show[Plot[{(1 + x)/3, -(1 + x)/3, x, -x}, {x, -1, 1},PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}},FrameLabel -> {x, y},Frame -> True, ImageSize -> imagesize],ContourPlot[f[e, p, 1]/3.05, {p, -1, 1}, {e, 0, 1}, Contours -> 12,PlotLegends -> {Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}},LegendLabel ->Style["PDF", FontSize -> 14, Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]],Below]}]]
```

Comment: You can use the `BarLegend` option `LegendMarkerSize` to change it's size.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. there were helpful. in the case of using "after" instead of "bottom", how can we have the label vertically next to the colorbar?